# renaming indexes into sequential strings in a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename

I need to changes the index in a data frame from 1:100 to item1:item100 automatically.
df.index=['item1', 'item2', ..., 'item100']

How can I do this without typing all the names?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Dummy data:    
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[1,2,3])

# Solution:
df.index = ["item{}".format(i) for i in df.index]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add scalar value to index converted to strings:

```
df.index = 'item' + df.index.astype(str)
```

For python 3.6+ is possible use `f-string`s:

```
df.index = [f"item{x}" for x in df.index]
```

If general index:

```
df.index = [f"item{x}" for x in range(1, len(df) + 1)]
```